# Android - how to use broadcast receiver to read SMS?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

In my android project I need to detect and read SMS texts as they come in, then call a function from another class.

How can I put the below code in a class and define it properly in the manifest. If I put this on another Java file, then I don't know how to call a function from another Java file. 
I tried putting this code in my main class but in my app, it just crashed.

```
public class SMSReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Parse the SMS.
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            // Retrieve the SMS.
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                // In case of a particular App / Service.
                //if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("+91XXX"))
                //{
                //str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                //str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                //}
            }
            if (str != "") { // remove the last \n
                str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
            }

            Reusable_CodeActivity.alert(my_ViewActivity.this, "AAAAAAAAAAA");
            try {
                //my_ViewActivity.this.handle_incoming_message(str);
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your manifest file. Also what do you mean by "crashed"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for receiving SMS is correct. but when you are using `BroadCastReceiver` in Activity class you need to unregister it as follows in onStop() method. I think this is the reason your activity was crushing.

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to receive broadcasts (when an SMS arrives) *while* your Activity is showing.

If so I found a nice pattern to do this a while back (Cant remember where I got it from, would be nice to give credit to the original author).

First, create an interface:

```
public interface Receiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
}
```

Now create a subclass of BroadcastReceiver which we can dynamically register at runtime:

```
public class PortableReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    public Receiver getReceiver() {
        return mReceiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (mReceiver != null)
            mReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);
        else
            Log.w("PortableReceiver", "Dropping received Result");
    }
}
```

Now we can use a PortableReceiver in the activity class:

```
public class MyActivity implements Receiver {
    private PortableReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReceiver = new PortableReceiver();
        mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Register the receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("_my_intent_action"); //TODO: add actions to filter just as you would in your AndroidManifest
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //TODO: Your code goes here!
    }
}
```

Now you have your Activity class directly handling the Broadcast, so you can access all the functionality it has available.

Note that if you want to *start* an activity from a BroadcastReceiver, thats a little different. If thats the case, I recommend you check out http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#pre_broadcastreceiver

Comment: is it possible to recieve the broadcast ,when the inbox opens ? @DanielGrech